# C++ XTree crash on exit, map/set iterator not dereferencable

Tags: c++, stdmap

I have some static classes with std::map's inside them, everything is working fine, but when i exit the program, it crashes with the error "map/set iterator not dereferencable".

Here are the maps:

```
struct DataSegment_P { std::string type; };
template <typename T> struct DataSegment : public DataSegment_P{ T value; };

static std::map<std::string, DataSegment_P*> data;
```

Another two:

```
static std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<sf::Texture>> textures;
static std::map<std::pair<std::string, std::vector<int>>, std::shared_ptr<sf::Sprite>> sprites;
```

And the last one:

```
struct Asset {
    std::map<std::string, std::string> values;
};

static std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Asset>>> assets;
```

I can't really paste the whole code here because it is thousands of lines long, but i'm clearing the maps as they should be.

Comment: Please create and post a [MCVE].

Comment: That is already the minimal, complete and verifiable example, just the fact that they exist, makes the application crash on exit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found the problem. I'm sorry but there was no way you could guess it, so im just pointing out the problem so if anyone like me can solve it.

I'm using SFML and i just found out that you can't use a smart pointer with a sf::RenderWindow inside it. That was what was causing the crash.